# How to resolve Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE error

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-pendingintent

I'm new to this site and coding as well so my question might not contain all the necessary information so please let me know if I need to add anything else. I am currently trying to create an app with React Native that I want to be able to communicate with the serial port and am currently trying to use the `react-native-usb-serialport-for-android` library I found online:

https://github.com/bastengao/react-native-usb-serialport-for-android

When I try to use the tryRequestPermissionMethod from the library, I get the error,

> Targeting S+ (version 21 ad above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

> checkFlags     PendingIntent.java:382
> getBroadcastAsUser      PendingIntent.java:673
> getBroadcast     PendingIntent.java:660
> tryRequestPermission     UsbSerialportForAndroidModule.java:99

The JAVA file with the ReactMethod for tryRequestPermission looks like this:

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void tryRequestPermission(int deviceId, Promise promise) {
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        UsbDevice device = findDevice(deviceId);
        if (device == null) {
            promise.reject(CODE_DEVICE_NOT_FOND, "device not found");
            return;
        }

        if (usbManager.hasPermission(device)) {
            promise.resolve(1);
            return;
        }

        PendingIntent usbPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getCurrentActivity(), 0, new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB), 0);
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, usbPermissionIntent);
        promise.resolve(0);
    }
```

and I'm currently using it in my project like so:

```
async function asyncCall() {

    const devices = await UsbSerialManager.list();
    console.log(devices)
    
    try {
        await UsbSerialManager.tryRequestPermission(1002);
        const usbSerialport = await UsbSerialManager.open(1002, { baudRate: 230400, parity: Parity.None, dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1 });

      
        const sub = usbSerialport.onReceived((event) => {
          console.log(event.deviceId, event.data);
        });

      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.code === Codes.DEVICE_NOT_FOND) {
          // ...
        }
      }
}
```

I've tried attempting the solutions from other posts changing the `PendingIntent` line from

```
PendingIntent usbPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getCurrentActivity(), 0, new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB), 0);
```

to

```
PendingIntent usbPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getCurrentActivity(), 0, new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

as well as adding `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'` to the `app/build.gradle` file, however I still get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it works in my project, try rebuild your project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).